# Permission denied error running javafx:run in IntelliJ on Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, javafx

I'm new to Linux (manjaro xfce) and this is my first maven/javafx project Im trying to setup. Everything seems to go smooth until I running javafx:run and get a permission error.

```
/home/ethan/.jdks/openjdk-14.0.1/bin/java "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/ethan/Desktop/coding/java/projects/OpenFX VLCj Music Player" -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/idea/plugins/maven/lib/maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/idea/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.ext.class.path=/usr/share/idea/plugins/maven/lib/maven-event-listener.jar -javaagent:/usr/share/idea/lib/idea_rt.jar=34865:/usr/share/idea/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/share/idea/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar:/usr/share/idea/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds.license org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2020.1.1 org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< com.ethanmdev:OpenFX-VLCj-Music-Player >---------------
[INFO] Building OpenFX-VLCj-Music-Player 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) @ OpenFX-VLCj-Music-Player ---
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/ethan/Desktop/coding/java/projects/OpenFX VLCj Music Player"): error=13, Permission denied
```

The error seems obvious that I just need to give the program "java" permission to run in this directory, but being new to Linux I don't want to jump in and try to change these permissions myself. Does anyone have a fix for this? And if it's neccecary to see the rest of the error stack let me know and I'll post the full thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this problem, open a terminal and run "sudo idea", do the regular intellij setup, and open your project. Giving idea sudo perms fixed the issue just fine.